# Let $G$ be a group. The inverse of $(g\cdot h)=h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}$, with $g, h \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If this is obvious and a silly question, I'm sorry. As a part of an exercise, I had to see that the inverse of $(g\cdot h)$, with $g$ and $h$ in a group $G$ is $h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}$. I proved it by this way:

Let $e$ be the neutral element on $G$:

\begin{equation}
(g\cdot h)^{-1} \cdot (g\cdot h)= e \\
\Downarrow \\(g\cdot h)^{-1} \cdot (g\cdot h)\cdot h^{-1}= e \cdot h^{-1}\\ \Downarrow\\ (g\cdot h)^{-1} \cdot g\cdot (h\cdot h^{-1})= e \cdot h^{-1} \\ \Downarrow\\ (g\cdot h)^{-1} \cdot g\cdot e= h^{-1} \\ \Downarrow \\ (g\cdot h)^{-1} \cdot g\cdot g^{-1}= h^{-1} \cdot g^{-1} \\ \Downarrow \\ (g\cdot h)^{-1} = h^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}
\end{equation}

Is that proof correct? Can I multiply the equation with elements of $G$ on both sides? Thank you!

Comment: Looks good! Though you can also prove the inverse must be unique, and $(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1}) = e$, so $(gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$. Your way works fine too!

Comment: Yes this is OK.

Comment: Perfectly correct

Comment: Once you made the calculation, you can of course condense your findings into $(gh)^{-1}= (gh)^{-1}e=(gh)^{-1}gg^{-1}=(gh)^{-1}geg^{-1}=(gh)^{-1}ghh^{-1}g^{-1}=(gh)^{-1}(gh)h^{-1}g^{-1}=eh^{-1}g^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$, if you wish

Comment: Your proof is fine. It would be easier, I think, to use existence, uniqueness of the inverse, and use associativity directly to prove that $(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1}=e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler proof is:$(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1}) = g(h h^{-1})g^{-1} = g g^{-1}=e$, and
similarly, $(h^{-1}g^{-1})(gh)=e$.  Hence $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$.